# Android Google Analytics doesnot report for uncaught crash and exception

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase, uncaughtexceptionhandler

I am creating an application in which I want to see the crash and exception report on the google analytics account.

I am using the following code for this functionality:

"analytics_global_config.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <resources>
  <string name="ga_appName">app_name</string>
  <string name="ga_logLevel">verbose</string>
  <integer name="ga_dispatchPeriod">1</integer>
  <bool name="ga_dryRun">true</bool>
</resources>
```

I have declared this xml in the manifest file as follows:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.globalConfigResource"
    android:resource="@xml/analytic_global_config" />
```

xml file for tracking: "analytics_track.xml" as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:ignore="TypographyDashes">
    <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-XXXXXXXX-1
     </string>
    <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true
     </bool>
    <bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true
     </bool>
    <string name="ga_sampleFrequency">99.8</string>
    <integer name="ga_sessionTimeout">2000</integer>
    <bool name="ga_anonymizeIp">true</bool>
```

In the application class I have used this code as follows:

```
Tracker tracker = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).(R.xml.analytics_track);
```

I am getting log on start of application as:

```
09-23 16:26:57.775: V/GAV4(7763): Thread[main,5,main]: Loading Tracker config values.
09-23 16:26:57.775: V/GAV4(7763): Thread[main,5,main]: [Tracker] trackingId loaded: UA- 54498004-1
09-23 16:26:57.775: V/GAV4(7763): Thread[main,5,main]: [Tracker] sample frequency loaded: 99.8
09-23 16:26:57.775: V/GAV4(7763): Thread[main,5,main]: [Tracker] session timeout loaded: 2000000
09-23 16:26:57.775: V/GAV4(7763): Thread[main,5,main]: [Tracker] auto activity tracking loaded: true
09-23 16:26:57.775: V/GAV4(7763): Thread[client_id_fetcher,5,main]: Loaded client id from disk.
09-23 16:26:57.775: V/GAV4(7763): Thread[main,5,main]: [Tracker] anonymize ip loaded: true
09-23 16:26:57.775: V/GAV4(7763): Thread[main,5,main]: [Tracker] anonymize ip loaded: false
09-23 16:26:57.785: V/GAV4(7763): Thread[main,5,main]: ExceptionReporter created, original handler is com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler
09-23 16:26:57.785: V/GAV4(7763): Thread[main,5,main]: Uncaught exceptions will be reported to Google Analytics.
09-23 16:27:02.895: V/GAV4(7763): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: connecting to Analytics service
09-23 16:27:02.985: V/GAV4(7763): Thread[main,5,main]: service connected, binder: android.os.BinderProxy@41ae4840
09-23 16:27:02.985: V/GAV4(7763): Thread[main,5,main]: bound to service
09-23 16:27:03.015: V/GAV4(7763): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: connect: bindService returned true for Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.analytics.service.START cmp=com.google.android.gms/.analytics.service.AnalyticsService (has extras) }
09-23 16:27:03.055: V/GAV4(7763): Thread[main,5,main]: Connected to service
09-23 16:27:03.445: I/GAV4(7763): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: No campaign data found.
09-23 16:27:03.445: V/GAV4(7763): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Initialized GA Thread
```

-after some time"

```
09-23 16:32:04.910: V/GAV4(7763): Thread[disconnect check,5,main]: Disconnecting due to     inactivity
09-23 16:32:04.920: V/GAV4(7763): Thread[disconnect check,5,main]: Disconnected from service
```

But the **issue** is that it is not giving uncaught crash and exception. I manually making eception and after exception I get the following logs as:

```
09-23 16:32:22.770: V/GAV4(7763): Thread[main,5,main]: Tracking Exception: ActivityNotFoundException (@FullVideoActivity:onCompletion:276) {main}
09-23 16:32:22.770: V/GAV4(7763): Thread[main,5,main]: Dispatch call queued. Dispatch will run once initialization is complete.
09-23 16:32:22.770: V/GAV4(7763): Thread[main,5,main]: Passing exception to original handler.
```

I am not getting any exception and crash on google analytics account.
Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Thanks
Ishan jain

Answer (score 0):

You are not sending the hit to the service. You should get after Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Initialized GA Thread the following:

```
    Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Loaded clientId
    Thread[GAThread,5,main]: putHit called
    Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Sending hit to service ..
```

In the application class you have to use:

```
 Tracker tracker = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).newTracker(R.xml.analytics_track);
```

If it is still not working you can also try to set GoogleAnalytics by adding the following method in onCreate() from your application class:

```
private void initGoogleAnalytics() {
    GoogleAnalytics mGoogleAnalytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
    mGoogleAnalytics.setDryRun(false);
    mGoogleAnalytics.setLocalDispatchPeriod(10);
    mGoogleAnalytics.getLogger().setLogLevel(Logger.LogLevel.VERBOSE);
    mGoogleAnalytics.enableAutoActivityReports(this);
}
```